# How do I preview a pdf file before saving it in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-views, django-templates

How do I preview a pdf file before saving it in Django?

I am trying to preview a pdf file before the user uploads it using the "pip install preview-generator" Link: https://pypi.org/project/preview-generator/

However the pdf file isn't loading up properly. I am not really sure what is pdf_or_odt_to_preview_path as the documentation wasn't clear.

As such, I tried to use JS and jquery to send information from the front end to views.py, and subsequently use the  tag to hold the pdf file.

First Attempt which didnt work as the file didnt show:
views.py

```
@login_required
def preview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        body = json.loads(request.body)
        embedPDF = body['PDF']
        print(PDF)
        cache_path = '/tmp/preview_cache'
        pdf_or_odt_to_preview_path = f'{PDF}'

        manager = PreviewManager(cache_path, create_folder= True)
        path_to_preview_image = manager.get_jpeg_preview(pdf_or_odt_to_preview_path)

        return JsonResponse({'status':200})
```

javascript:

```
$('#testing-nia').on('change', function () {
  const file = this.files[0]
  reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  $(reader).on('load', function() {
    PDF = this.result
    var request = new Request(
                "{% url 'preview' %}",
                {headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{csrf_token}}'}}
              )

    fetch(request, {
              method: 'POST',
              mode: 'same-origin',
              body: JSON.stringify({'PDF' : PDF, 
                                  })
          })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log('finished if false'))
  })
})
```

2nd Attempt which rendered a header i dont want:

javascript:

```
    else if (file.name.endsWith('pdf')) {
      reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      $(reader).on('load', function () {
        // $('.PDF').hide()
        $('#PDF').attr('src', this.result);
        $('#filename-upload').html(file.name)
        input_filename()
      })
```

html

```
<embed src="" id='embedPDF' name='embedPDF' class='d-none' type="application/pdf" width="690px" height="380px">
```

[image]

Comment: did you try rendering it using html and css?

Answer (score 0):

Install `xhtml2pdf`

In your app create a file called `render.py` and in it put this code.

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa
from html import escape as html_escape

class Render:
    @staticmethod
    def render(path: str, context: dict):
        template = get_template(path)
        html = template.render(context)
        response = BytesIO()
        pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), response)
        if not pdf.err:
            return HttpResponse(response.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
        else:
            return  HttpResponse("Error handling pdf", status=400)
```

then in your `views.py`

```
from .render import Render
@login_required
def preview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #function that fetches the pdf
        context = { }
        return Render.render('template_to_render_pdf.html', context)
```

in your `template_to_render_pdf.html` include this css

```
<style type="text/css">
            @page {
                size: A4;
                margin: 1cm;
            }
</style>
```

Comment: Hey bro thanks but I am trying to convert from pdf to image, not html to pdf